# Output need Base64 format using cordova image resizer

Tags: cordova, ionic2, image-resizing

I am using ionic 2 and I need image resize. Because i used this plugin

ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/protonet/cordova-plugin-image-resizer.git

```
 npm install --save @ionic-native/image-resizer
```

Here is my code.

```
import { NavController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ImagePicker } from '@ionic-native/image-picker';
import { Camera } from 'ionic-native';
import { ImageResizer, ImageResizerOptions } from '@ionic-native/image-resizer';
declare var window: any;

constructor(public alertCtrl: AlertController,private imageResizer: ImageResizer,public platform: Platform,private imagePicker: ImagePicker) {
}

    Choosephoto()
  {
    const options  =   {
        maximumImagesCount: 3, // Android only since plugin version 2.1.1, default no limit
        quality: 90, // 0-100, default 100 which is highest quality
        width: 400,  // proportionally rescale image to this width, default no rescale
        height: 400, // same for height
         destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
         sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
         encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,      
         correctOrientation: true,
         outputType: 1 // default .FILE_URI
    }
    this.imagePicker.getPictures(options).then((results) => {
      var arr = [];

          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

          this.base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + results[i];
          //console.log("Image URL",this.base64Image);

          if(this.images.length == 0)
          {
              arr.push({
              file:this.base64Image
            })
            this.images=arr;
          }
          else if(this.images.length != 0)
          {
              this.images.push({
              "file":this.base64Image
            })
          }

          let options1 = {
           uri: this.base64Image,
           quality: 90,
           width: 100,
           height: 100,
           outputType:""  
          } as ImageResizerOptions;


          this.imageResizer
            .resize(options1)
            .then((filePath: any) => {
              var image=new Image();
              image.src=filePath;
              var path=image.src;
              console.log("called function");
              this.convertToDataURLviaCanvas(filePath, 'image/png').then(
                data => {
                  console.log(data);
                  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                    title: data.toString(),
                    buttons: ['Dismiss']
                  });
                  alert.present();
                }
              );
              console.log('FilePath', filePath)

             })
            .catch(e => console.log("Failedresizeerr",e));

          }
        }, (err) => { console.log(err)});

  }
```

It's work fine.The result is Filepath. But I need base64string format.

How can i do this.

I have no idea.

Thanks.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, you need base64 string only, no files to be stored in the device?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.I dont understand.what did u say?

Comment: I meant, You need the base64 string right, but this plugin returns only the url, where the file is stored. So you have two options, modify the java code in that plugin to return the base64 string or you can convert the image file url to base64 in the frontend. ie. Typescript/javascript

Comment: Thanks.how can i convert Localpath URI to base64

Answer (score 1):

Ok, What I did is similar to your method, used the image picker plugin, loaded the image via this plugin, resized it using the image resize plugin and displayed the Base64 string.

**Here is the code:**

```
  getImage() {
    let options = {
      maximumImagesCount: 3,
      width: 400,
      height: 400,
      quality: 90,
      outputType: 0
    };
    this.imagePicker.getPictures(options).then((results) => {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        this.imageurlfrompicker = results[i];
        let resizeoptions = {
          uri: results[i],
          folderName: 'demofolder',
          quality: 90,
          width: 1280,
          height: 1280
        } as ImageResizerOptions;
        this.imageResizer
          .resize(resizeoptions)
          .then((filePath: string) => {
            this.imageurlfromresizer = filePath;
            this.convertToBase64(filePath, 'image/png').then(
              data => {
                this.imagebase64 = data.toString();
              }
            );
          })
          .catch(e => console.log(e));
      }
    }, (err) => { });
  }

  convertToBase64(url, outputFormat) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let img = new Image();
      img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
      img.onload = function () {
        let canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.createElement('CANVAS'),
          ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
          dataURL;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        canvas.width = img.width;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
        canvas = null;
        resolve(dataURL);
      };
      img.src = url;
    });
  }
```

**Screenshot :**

[image]

[Get the full working project from my repository](https://github.com/darthranjith/ImageConvert)

Comment: I called convertToBase64() inside imageresizer.i passed the filepath value.

Comment: are you running the project in browser (ionic serve) or Device?

Comment: Please see the updated answer. I think this would suffice you :)

Comment: Still.does not alert any value.My path is file:///storage/emulated/0/1495518539503.jpg.I select image from gallery using Image picker.

Comment: can you send me the project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144896/discussion-between-ranjith-varadan-and-anisundar).

Comment: If you are still interested, please check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks.Your cordova version  ?

Comment: My version is 6.5.0

Comment: @ANISUNDAR if you are convinced this answer solved your problem, please accept it as answer.

Comment: I dont understand what u say?

Comment: Please read this [How to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). It's a good practice to follow these steps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need that feature but it got implemented in the image resizer, just try something like that:

```
var options = {
  uri: imageURI,
  folderName: "Test Folder",
  fileName: "test.jpg",
  quality: 90,
  width: 1280,
  height: 1280,
  base64: true
};

window.ImageResizer.resize(options,
  function(image) {
    console.log("yeah, resized and it's in base64: ", image)
  }, function() {
    console.log("nope... error!")
  }
);
```